# Refused to connect to 'blob:http://XXX' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, angular10

I'm using "URL.createObjectURL(blob);" to pass this URL to my "src", to load [xeokit](https://xeokit.github.io/xeokit-sdk/examples/#BIMOffline_XKT_Duplex) viewer, it work's correctly on windows locally, but if try with docker or ubuntu server it doesn't work.

i'm also adding this to my index.html header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="
      worker-src blob:;
      child-src blob: gap:;
       style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:;
       script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:;
       object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:;
       img-src * 'self' blob: data:;
       connect-src * blob: data: gap:;
       frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;
       default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:;">
```

but i still have the same error.

Comment: As you can see in the error message, the violated directive is `connect-src 'self'`, but your `<meta CSP>` contains `connect-src * blob: data: gap:;`. This means you have second more strict CSP published some where. Quote possible it's a default CSP published by server via HTTP header.

Comment: thnak you for the response, i will check this